# Tmux remapping prefix key

Tags: tmux

What does the following section do in the tmux config file?

```
# remap prefix
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send-prefix
```

I know functionally it is changing the prefix mapping of `C-b` to `C-a`, but why does this require three lines to do that?

It seems to me the `unbind` removes the default `C-b` as prefix. But then how do the other two work? (Also, is the last line necessary?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two lines `unbind` and `set` do the prefix remapping.
The last line is necessary, even though without it, you can already use `c-a` as prefix key.

Imagine, now your prefix is `c-a`, now you open vim in a tmux window, you want to increment a number by `c-a`, how can you do it? When you pressed `c-a` tmux will capture it as the tmux prefix, now you need some key to send the original `c-a` to the process(vim).

Same example when you edit command line with emacs binding. You want your cursor to move to the BOL by `c-a`.

The last line will allow a process to accept `c-a` in tmux window, by pressing `c-a` twice.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to [Kent's aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532931/9157799), you actually don't need `unbind C-b` since [you can only have one main prefix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29884/307359). So basically you only need two lines to remap a prefix key.